# Tidy up rails6 tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It seems the tag rails6 (14 questions) may be unnecessary given ruby-on-rails-6 has > 1000 questions. Should rails6 be combined into the ruby-on-rails-6 tag?

Note: 'ruby-on-rails-6' is consistent with other ruby-on-rails-* tags

Comment: rails6 syn'd and merged into ruby-on-rails-6 - that makes it consistent with how all the previous versions have been handled...

Comment: @JonClements purely out of interest, what is syn'd?

Comment: "syn'd" == "synonymised" - but without the struggle of remembering quite how to spell it :)